# Create a trigger on project group that after update of group_grade, update the student-grade of students of that group

Tags: sql-server-2008

These tables can be joined by simple join, but since I have different user_role the joining part is a bit more difficult.

Here is the code how I join these tables:

```
select 
    g.group_name, u.first_name
from  
    Group1 g 
join 
    Student_Group sg on g.groupid = sg.groupid
join 
    User1 u on sg.userid = u.userid
join 
    User_Role ur on u.userid = ur.userid
join 
    Role1 r on ur.roleid = r.roleid
where 
    r.name = 'Student'
```

Comment: first part of the question though (I assume) is `create a trigger...`  which isn't shown.  you are going to have people trying to guess what you are asking, or have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

--hmm this is how I think to do this Dave

ALTER TRIGGER update_stud_grade_trigger 
       ON  group1
       AFTER UPDATE 
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON; 
        UPDATE student
        SET student.student_grade = Group1.grade / Count(User.userid)
        
        FROM INSERTED ins
        join group1 g on ins.groupid = g . Groupid
        join Student_Group sg on g.groupid = sg.groupid

```
    join User1 u on sg.userid = u.userid
    join User_Role ur on u.userid = ur.userid
    join Role1 r on ur.roleid = r.roleid
where r.name = 'Student' and ins.group_grade = '10' 

END
```